# I need get max row from table

Tags: sql

I have table like this:

```
id | idx | cost
1    1     500
2    1     1000
3    2     500
4    2     9000
```

I need get max `cost` where `id=@id`

So I wrote this query:

```
SELECT   Id
FROM    table
WHERE (cost= (SELECT MAX(cost) AS Expr1 FROM  table AS table_1)) AND (idx= @idx)
```

but this only work when cost is max of all on the tabe

I need get id of max cost where `idx=@idx`

Comment: Does this actually relate to C#, or is that tag here by mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `top (1)` clause :

```
select top (1) t.*
from table t
where idx = @id
order by cost desc;
```

Comment: tank a lot , my problem fixed

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `order by` and something to liit to one row:

```
select t.*
from t
where id = @id
order by cost desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: tank a lot , my problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE idx = @idx AND cost = (SELECT MAX(cost) FROM table WHERE idx = @idx);`